# Where have you gone Señor Santa Claus?

Tags: lateral-thinking, knowledge, language, geography, cryptic-clues

Santa is exhausted, so he drops off his reindeer at the marked location below.
He tells them he will be strolling the large divided meadow if they need him.

Where is Santa, and why?

Please reference this map:

[image: Where is Santa?]

**Hints:**

> Neither Santa nor his reindeer are in Brooklyn.
>  Think outside the box but inside the correct -zoid, take everything into account.
>  The reindeer are ensnared and cannot leave. They need your help!
>  Santa thinks that its the best place in the area for reindeer.

Comment: 1) is Santa at that spot, or just the reindeer? 2) is (whoever) *exactly* at that spot?

Comment: @question_asker just the reindeer are at the marked location.

Comment: Is that specific location important, or is it just that it's nearby to where Santa went?

Comment: @question_asker I see why you are the question_asker now XD. If I told you I would have to krill you. Its a sort of metaphor, and its near by, a bit of both.

Comment: Well, it's necessary information—I need to know whether I need to pay special attention to the addresses (since there's nothing of note around there) or if I'm just "somewhere in the vicinity"

Comment: @question_asker Think outside the box, and don't focus on the actual address, I don't even know what the address is. I don't want to spoil it so that is all I'll say.

Comment: I'm way outside the box already - though it turns out I'm still just inside a bigger box

Comment: Is the location close to Hamilton Metz?

Comment: Why is Santa Spanish (or Mexican)??

Comment: Looks like he left the reindeer right outside Izzy's BBQ Smokehouse -- I'm beginning to fear the worst (and the tastiest) for Donner and Blitzen.

Comment: Rio Grande? (See: http://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/jimreeves/seorsantaclaus.html)

Comment: Maybe he's in Istanbul, not Constantinople.

Comment: Voters: please be more careful with upvotes. I'm seeing a lot of answers treat this question as a joke, yet get upvotes anyway - not to mention that many of these answers don't contain any more effort than a single sentence. **The quality of the site is in your hands. Please vote carefully.**

Comment: @Emrakul Why would you think we don’t? The community builds the quality it wants, be it jokes or serious answers.

Comment: Should I look further into Corona, which is, at least according to Wikipedia, the “gateway to the Inland Empire”?

Comment: @Édouard Computer says no.

Comment: Do I need to open google maps to answer this?

Comment: @ATM no but it would help, though I wouldn't be looking in NYC. Think of it as a pseudo map.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure how specific it needs to be, but I'm guessing Señor Santa is in...

> Reno, Nevada!

How the map fits:

> We were told that nobody's actually in NYC, but the 'zoid is right. The area of interest on the map is roughly trapezoidal. So is Nevada.

How the language fits:

> [@Solocutor](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/19128/solocutor) did the dirty work for part of this one:
>  Meadow (Nava) + Divided (Dividido) $\approx$ **Nevada**
>
>  And I found that...
>  Reindeer = **Reno**

The reindeer need help because...

> They are ***trap*** ped in the ***-zoid***... And Santa may very well have wandered on over to the Strip to relieve his stress.

Comment: You sir are on my level.

Comment: Though technically the answer I'm after is "Santa is in Las Vegas, and his Reindeer are in Reno" you are very much correct. Congratulations.

Comment: Eyyy, last spoiler. I guessed as much. :P

Answer (score 8):

I can't quite get to the right answer because...

> my Spanish isn't good enough.

So I'll try to help the effort along.

> Senor Santa implies Spanish language puns, so...
>  Meadow = Nava
>  Divided = Dividido
>  Merry Christmas = *Feliz Navidad*  (Nava dividido)

I think that's the heart of the thing.  Here's some extras:

> Feliz = Happy (There is also a shop named Feliz near this spot in Brooklyn, less than a mile to the northwest).
>  That shop is next to Fort Greene Park; a divided meadow itself.

Comment: OP has hinted that neither reindeer nor Santa are in Brooklyn.

Comment: Yeah, I know that.  That's why the "Feliz" part is under "extras."  I didn't want to leave it out, in case is was relevant.  The rest of the answer still stands.

Comment: @Solocutor your on the right track but not quite on point. Remember if we don't find him no presents.

Answer (score 6):

He is strolling in [Long Meadow](https://goo.gl/maps/Rwt87wMNa2D2) in Prospect Park, just over [2 miles west](https://goo.gl/maps/fj3TdQfhxD42) of the reindeer landing spot.

As the name implies, it is a *large meadow*, and it has been *divided* into ballfields in the south and open meadow in the north.

As for why Santa is there, [this site](http://www.nycgo.com/venues/prospect-park-long-meadow) claims that this is a popular location for children's birthday parties.  Santa is obviously doing some reconnaissance to populate his naughty/nice list.

Comment: Sorry I checked there.

Answer (score 5):

I think

> Santa is in the Greek underworld

He is exhausted

> He is tired and about to die.

Looking at the map,

> there are lots of graveyards nearby.

He will be strolling the large divided meadow if they need him.

> The Greek underworld is divided into several sections: the Fields of Punishment, the Fields of Asphodel, and Elysium. Santa probably expects to be in Elysium. It's kind of hard to "stroll" the Fields of Punishment, and he probably won't be able to remember or help the reindeer in the Fields of Asphodel.

Theory:

> His reindeer is bringing him to his funeral.

Dunno why he's called "Señor" though.

Answer (score -1):

He is in the North Pole, because today is not Christmas.

Answer (score -1):

Going a bit off the wall here:

> The marked location appears to be a BBQ place. I'll say that Santa is exhausted from dealing with all their workplace drama and dropped them off to be made into tasty meals. Santa is at the North Pole now, because he got his order to go. And the reindeer aren't much of anywhere, unless you count *INSIDE SANTA* Muahahahahahaha!

Answer (score -2):

Going for the obvious:

> He's strolling in the large divided meadow because he's exhausted.
>
>  Ugh! An anti-puzzle??

Answer (score -3):

given that he is exhausted, he has not moved from the marked location.

Comment: He certainly left his reindeer a significant walking distance from any kind of meadow